# Update jquery version in Liferay 7.2

Tags: jquery, liferay-7

For security reasons, I need to update the version of jQuery in 7.2 Community edition of Liferay.  It is currently using jQuery version 3.4 and I need to update to 3.5.

I have tried actually disabling jQuery in the control panel. I thought this might make 3.4 unavailable and I could then include a reference to 3.5 in my theme. However, disabling jQuery in the control panel broke the login form and control panel.

It would seem that a hook would be a good approach for this. I have found some info on 7.2 that allows you to override js functions but not the entire library.

How would you go about this?

Comment: I don't know liferay, but if it is dependent upon 3.4, things could break. Is it not possible to simply edit the source and change the version number? It seems that their dev resources may have an answer, but I don't have login to know.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 3.5.0 included a regression that causes panels within the control menu not being collapsed.
If you have access to fix packs, you can patch your Portal with fix pack 7 which will upgrade your jQuery to 3.5.1.
More info here:
https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-114587
https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-112136

If you don't have access to fix packs, here are the files where you need to change the jQuery version:
modules/apps/frontend-js/frontend-js-jquery-web/package.json
modules/yarn.lock